How to fix netplan on Ubuntu 22.04 running in VM on windows 10?
I always have issues with the netplan config, even I thought I finally understood what is going on...
Anyway, I have the following configuration in /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml:
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    first:
      match: {macaddress: "3c:e9:f7:a7:1c:0f"}
      set-name: "wifi"
      dhcp4: yes
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 1.1.1.1 

The command ip link show shows the following output:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: cas10: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wifi: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:e9:f7:a7:1c:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s9
4: wired: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a9:09:5a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s10
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
    link/ether 02:42:14:1b:d7:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

but when I run sudo netplan apply I get a bunch of warnings:
** (generate:3512): WARNING **: 13:50:08.032: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.
WARNING:root:Cannot call Open vSwitch: ovsdb-server.service is not running.

** (process:3510): WARNING **: 13:50:08.432: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

** (process:3510): WARNING **: 13:50:08.432: Permissions for /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml are too open. Netplan configuration should NOT be accessible by others.

I never had used "ovsdb-server" before, so why does that pop up now suddenly?
Also the permissions seems to be ok:
$ ls -l /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 411 Sep  3 13:41 /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

For the VM I have this configuration for the "wifi" adaptor which creates the connection to the internet:

So how to fix these issues?
I now can ping 8.8.8.8 but I cannot ping google.com even I added the nameserver settings...

If you can ping 8.8.8.8, then your network works. Netplan works. Vitualbox works. What leads you to believe that you must specify nameservers? Is this really a question about DNS resolution?

I had exactly this problem. I was able to ping 8.8.8.8 but not a URL like google.com. Actually I saw this problem when doing git pull in a repo and the address could not be resolved, but I was able to ping 8.8.8.8 (and git pull did work on the windows host ...)
